# MYSQL - limiting joins

Tags: mysql, join

I know this subject has been covered before on here but I need a different result to the other questions.

I need to order some results on institution name and then candidates last name.

```
SELECT DISTINCT candidates.*, histories.job_title, institutions.name
FROM candidates
JOIN histories ON histories.candidate_id = candidates.id
JOIN institutions ON histories.institution_id = institutions.id
WHERE candidates.id IN (1,3,4,6)
ORDER BY institutions.name, candidates.last_name;
```

My problem is currently this will return all the candidates joined histories(there current/past employments) but if I add

```
AND histories.finish_date IS NULL
```

To the where it won't return candidates who don't have a history or have a finish date set.

Thanks, Alex

Sub Query

```
SELECT DISTINCT candidates.*, 
   (SELECT institution_id
        FROM histories
        WHERE histories.candidate_id = candidates.id AND histories.finish_date IS NULL
        LIMIT 1) AS job_title       
   FROM candidates
  JOIN institutions ON histories.institution_id = institutions.id
WHERE candidates.id IN (1,3,4,6)
```

Comment: Alex: I realised after posting my suggestion that there are problems with it, and so I've deleted it. Sorry to have taken up your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a left join on the histories table:

```
SELECT DISTINCT candidates.*, histories.job_title, institutions.name
FROM candidates
LEFT JOIN histories ON histories.candidate_id = candidates.id AND histories.finish_date IS NULL
JOIN institutions ON histories.institution_id = institutions.id
WHERE candidates.id IN (1,3,4,6)
ORDER BY institutions.name, candidates.last_name;
```

I can't verify this, you'll have to do it for me. It should return all the candidates, and their histories (if they have one).

Comment: Thanks, that returned 3 of the 4 but the fourth has a finish date set i.e he is currently not employed. how would i get it to include him as well ?

Comment: @Alex try my modified version, without the AND clause.

Comment: Thanks, I don't think I explained it very well. I only want to return the 4 candidates with there most resent history(finish_date set to null) but in some cases the candidate may not have a histories but they should still get returned

Comment: @Alex alright, try this version with the restrictive finish_date clause in the join.

Comment: Thanks for the reply I got it to the same stage, it returns 3 candidates but it doesn't return the last because the candidate has no history. Is there a way to return the candidate even thou he has no history ?